# Reading binary file into array in Objective-C [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, binary

I want to read binary file on my iPhone.
I have .txt file which stores information about an array: `int[6000][9]`
How can I put this data into an array in my code?

I tried this:

```
int mapa1[6000][9];

NSFileHandle* file = [NSFileHandle fileHAndleForReadingAtPAth: @"level1.txt"];
[[file readDataOfLength:4] getBytes:mapa1];
mapa1 = NSSwapLittleIntToHost(mapa1);
```

But on the last line I receive error: "Incompatible types in assigment"
So I don't know how to copy this binary file into the array...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

mapa1 is not an unsigned int, which is what the returnvalue of NSSwapLittleIntHost is.